# Replace underscore in macro implementation?

Tags: cross-referencing, underscore

I'm working on a document that contains a set of sections describing some technical objects. The object names contain underscores (very common in that programming environment), so I've loaded the package `underscore`.

Now I want to link from other parts of the document to the reference section. Underscores in labels (e. g. `\label{sec:ref-struct-FOO_BAR}`) seem to cause all kinds of trouble, so I've simply replaced the underscores with dashes in the labels: `\label{sec:ref-struct-FOO-BAR}`. This works so far.

As a next step, I would like to provide a custom macro that is called with the object name (containing an underscore) and then both typesets that name (with an underscore) and places a link (where all underscores are replaced by dashes). An example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{underscore} 

\newcommand{\componentname}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\newcommand{\structurename}[1]{\texttt{#1}}

\newcommand{\componentref}[2]{\hyperref[sec:ref-comp-#1]{\componentname{#2}}}
\newcommand{\structureref}[2]{\hyperref[sec:ref-struct-#1]{\structurename{#2}}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\clearpage

\section{Text}

% Where I came from:
We use component \componentname{AB_CD} (see \fref{sec:ref-comp-AB-CD}) to generate 
structure \structurename{FOO_BAR} (see \fref{sec:ref-struct-FOO-BAR}).

% How far I got:
We use component \componentref{AB-CD}{AB_CD} to generate structure \structureref{FOO-BAR}{FOO_BAR}.

% What I really want:
% We use component \componentref{AB_CD} to generate structure \structureref{FOO_BAR}.

\section{Reference}

\subsection{Structures}

\subsubsection{Structure \structurename{FOO_BAR}}
\label{sec:ref-struct-FOO-BAR}

Text

\subsubsection{Structure \structurename{BOO_FAR}}
\label{sec:ref-struct-BOO-FAR}

Text

\subsection{Components}


\subsubsection{Component \componentname{AB_CD}}
\label{sec:ref-comp-AB-CD}

Text

\subsubsection{Component \componentname{EFG_HIJ}}
\label{sec:ref-comp-EFG-HIJ}

Text

\end{document}
```

I'd like to use something like

```
\usepackage{xstring}
% ...
\newcommand{\fancycomponentref}[1]{\hyperref[sec:ref-comp-\StrSubstitute{#1}{_}{-}]{\componentname{#1}}}
```

but that doesn't work, and I haven't found a viable solution yet. What options do I have to implement this?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the `underscore` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyref}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\componentname}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\newcommand{\structurename}[1]{\texttt{#1}}

\newcommand{\componentref}[1]{\hyperref[sec:ref-comp-#1]{\componentname{#1}}}
\newcommand{\structureref}[1]{\hyperref[sec:ref-struct-#1]{\structurename{#1}}}

\begingroup\lccode`~=`_ \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}_
\catcode`_=12

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\clearpage

\section{Text}

% Where I came from:
We use component \componentname{AB_CD} (see \fref{sec:ref-comp-AB_CD}) to generate 
structure \structurename{FOO_BAR} (see \fref{sec:ref-struct-FOO_BAR}).

% How far I got:
We use component \componentref{AB_CD} to generate structure \structureref{FOO_BAR}.

\section{Reference}

\subsection{Structures}

\subsubsection{Structure \structurename{FOO_BAR}}
\label{sec:ref-struct-FOO_BAR}

Text and math $a_1$

\subsubsection{Structure \structurename{BOO_FAR}}
\label{sec:ref-struct-BOO_FAR}

Text

\subsection{Components}


\subsubsection{Component \componentname{AB_CD}}
\label{sec:ref-comp-AB_CD}

Text

\subsubsection{Component \componentname{EFG_HIJ}}
\label{sec:ref-comp-EFG_HIJ}

Text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The "real" application is a 480+-page document with a lot of stuff in it. I've tried to replace the `underscore` package with your catcode enchantments, but I get "missing $ inserted" errors all over the place. I don't even know where I should start to find out where that comes from... :-(

Comment: @vwegert Sorry, but without a minimal example it's impossible to say more.

Comment: I understand that. While I got the message that in this particular minimal example, I don't need the `underscore` package, is there a way to get this working without removing the package?

Comment: @vwegert `underscore` makes the underscore active, with a non expandable definition, so `_` can't be used in labels.

Comment: ...which is why I've replaced it -- manually -- in the labels. Now I would like to replace it -- automatically -- in the custom referencing macros, but the high-level `xstring` macros that I normally use seem to fail here.

Comment: @vwegert They fail for the same reason: they are not fully expandable, so they can't be used in a `\label`.

Comment: @egreg, are there any drawbacks of using your catcode magic when creating a template for a journal? I am needing it to create my own \doi command (as some DOI include underscores).

Comment: @Alberto for such an application I’d do differently. Look for  `\detokenize`